# How to insert data taken from a field of a document into a global boolean variable in Firebase with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a "Users" collection in Firebase with all accounts saved. Among the fields of each user there is a Boolean field that indicates whether or not he can access some features. I would now like to create a global variable bool with the variable taken from the Firebase field inside and then a global function that updates this variable in case it changes (for example with logout-login of another account).

For now I have created a variable.dart file with inside:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

bool auth = false;
String? email = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email;

void authUpdate() async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Users')
      .doc(email)
      .get()
      .then((value) async {
    auth = value.data()!['auth?'];
  });
}
```

The idea is to call the authUpdate() function when the user presses the login button and then use the auth variable when I need it, but this system doesn't work because the auth variable is not updated with value.data()!['auth?'].
How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you show us your login button code? you need to make sure that you call await authUpdate() to get the updated value only after it completes

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the code that doesn't see the updated value is outside of the `sync` method.

Data is loaded from Firestore (and most cloud APIs) asynchronously. Rather than blocking the app until the data has loaded, the main code of your app continues to run and then when the data is available, your `then` block is called.

This is easiest to see when add some some logging:

```
print('Before starting to load data');
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(email)
    .get()
    .then((value) async {
  print('Got data')
});
print('After starting to load data');
```

When you run this code, the output is:

> Before starting to load data
> After starting to load data
> Got data

Now you may think that the `await` keyword you added changes this order, but it actually only does that **inside** your `authUpdate` function. Outside of that, the behavior becomes asynchronous again.

For example:

```
void authUpdate() async {
  var value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Users')
      .doc(email)
      .get()
      .then((value) async {
  auth = value.data()!['auth?'];    
  print('Got data')
}

...

// Somewhere else...
print('Before calling authUpdate');
authUpdate();
print('After calling authUpdate');
```

When you run this, the output will be:

> Before calling authUpdate
> After calling authUpdate
> Got data

This is because `authUpdate` is an asynchronous function, so if you want to wait for its asynchronous behavior to finish, you'll have to `await` it:

```
print('Before calling authUpdate');
await authUpdate();
print('After calling authUpdate');
```

When you run this, the output will be:

> Before calling authUpdate
> Got data
> After calling authUpdate

The main lessons here are:

- When calling asynchronous APIs, you need to ensure you **always** wait for its behavior.
- Using `await` makes the code **in that block/function** *seem* synchronous.
- But the block/function itself is still asynchronous, so you need to `await` that.